# Password protect a website only if it is the dev site

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, htpasswd

I am trying to password protect a website only if it is the dev site using .htaccess and .htpasswd

I am using Apache 2.4.29 on Ubuntu 18.04

Here is what I have in the .htaccess file

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'dev.randy.dev'">
  AuthUserFile "/home/randy/.htpasswd"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "dev"
  require valid-user
</If>
```

I confirmed that the password protection lines do indeed work outside of the IF.

When I try to run the above I get the apache internal server error.  I have checked the main apache error.log as well as the virtualhost error log and nothing is being reported in either.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do or should I go about it another way?

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are getting? You mention it but didn't tell us what it is/was.

Comment: These directives look syntactically valid, so it's not clear what would be triggering the error. If you are getting a 500 Internal Server Error then you would expect an error to be logged somewhere (providing error logs are configured) - which is another mystery. Do you get the error regardless of which _hostname_ you access the site through?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? What is the `AllowOverride` directive set to in your `<VirtualHost>`?

Comment: My apologies for not getting back to everyone sooner.  It turns out the dev server I was testing this on did not have the required version of Apache. I think I checked my local apache version when drafting the question but then tested on a server that had Apache 2.2.

Comment: @RandyJohnson And Apache expressions don't exist on Apache 2.2 (hence the error). So, is your query now resolved?